# Alternative to Google's 'Keep'

Tags: gratis, note-taking, hosted

On the site 'keep.google.com' you can organize notes, lists, todo's which you can access from any place via browser. However, this can become chaotic with a lot of notes, and not sure if Google will keep this service.

What free alternatives do I have to create notes à la OneNote, but accessible via browser? I also want to access my notes from different platforms (Windows, Linux, Android).

Comment: This is the wrong question. Since Google Keep does not work for you, you should ask for "Software that does X", then add what you have already tried (and why it does not work). Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and maybe [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) and [edit] your question. I have already edited your tags.

Comment: I my view this is a valid question. There is a solution (google's keep) and I am asking for similar software.

Comment: Having said that, you are not the first person looking for a note-taking webapp. Use the search box in the upper right, e.g. [searching for the note-taking tag](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/note-taking)

Comment: "this can become chaotic with a lot of notes" <- please describe the problem in more details, otherwise we might propose software with the same problems. How many is a lot? What happens then? What should happen instead?

Comment: Are you using tags? It makes lots of notes manageable.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft now has [OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/) on the web for free!! it is accessable from the web, you can connect it to Office's OneNote, there are apps for Android, IOS, Mac, Windows and Apple watch now!

Answer (score 2):

I believe EverNote can function as you desire:

```
https://evernote.com/pricing/
```

I have used EverNote; and you can access your EverNote items from any PC (web browser - Win/Linux/Mac), as well as up to two (2) devices for **free**. It works really well, and I've not had any issues with reliability.

Also, in addition to "just" notes, for **free** you can:

```
Upload up to 60 MB per month
Stay organized across platforms
Clip web pages and images
Search for text inside images
Share and discuss notes
Add passcode lock on mobile apps
Integrates with Google Drive
```

... and it does in-line images as well:

[image: Evernote In-Line Image Sample]

Finally, in the vein of a "todo" list... to any "note" you can add a [checkbox] to function in the traditional manner.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Trello](https://trello.com/home) will suit you?

There is a free offering but you can pay for more features. Multiple 'boards', collaberation features (if that is of interest), and pretty straightforward to use.

In short, you can create multiple boards, each board is typically divided in to swim-lanes or stacks, and each stack contains multiple cards. It's ideal for running an electronic [Kanban Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_board)...

Comment: Please describe how to use Trello to organize notes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Trello as well! I've actually got an entire system I use to organize my life with Trello - it helps me actually get things done and see how much value I'm adding and not just how hard I'm working on something. Plus, it helps me manage lots of bigger projects all the way down to the granular details.
In case you want to check out my post about my system, here it is http://www.project1440.co/blog/organize-your-life-with-trello-5-steps/